# Where is environment.yml located

Tags: python, conda

Where are the requirements.txt and environment.yml files located when created via the following commands in a conda venv.

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

`conda env export > environment.yml --no-builds`

Can't find them any where in any directory in Finder on MacOS. Have looked in opt/miniconda3/envs/my_venv

Comment: those would both be created in the working directory where you executed those shell commands. Note, this is really a `bash`/shell question

Comment: Also, i'm pretty sure `conda env export > environment.yml --no-builds` should be something like `conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.